# Mongodb creating a field that has the sum of multiple values inside the same document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

As the title say, I want to make a function in a document that sums all coins into TotalCoins for a specific user in mongodb . I found [$add](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) but I didn't know how to solve the problem with it.

PS: I'm using Mongodb, mongoose nodejs express

I have a User collection which has coins gained by this USER A  and other coins with a percentage of other users that got referred by this USER A.

So the user schema looks like this

```js
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5abcbee7ff1e4849b8f642b5"
    },
    "name": "test1",
    "email": "test1@gmail.com",
    "username": "test1",
    "password": "$2a$10$/Y6Gns8OPsp8eudVBrfUx.clwNwixAmeqhVzBYKUyNuoGcR3XQP8e",
    "joindate": "29/03/2018 11:24",
    "lastdailybonus": "28/03/2018 11:24",
    "profileimgurl": "img.jpg",
    "referralUrl": "r1xk1rq5g",
    "referredBy":"syiqyb9cz",
    "referredUsers": [
        {
            "id": {
                "$oid": "5abcbf29ff1e4849b8f642b6"
            },
            "coins": 50
        },
        {
            "id": {
                "$oid": "5abcbf9b9a3ca4425489777e"
            },
            "coins": 76
        }
    ],
    "completedMissions": [],
    "coinsEarned":1500,
    "__v": 2
}
```

I want to have a new field TotalCoins which adds the sum of CoinsEarned and the coins in the referredUsers array (iterate through the array and sums the coins ) And this array can be extended when the users refer new friends. is it possible To achieve this operation ? It is complex and if its impossible do you have any alternatives ? :) Thanks for your time

**UPDATE**

Using aggregate: it's the same code you guys posted below but with some modification. unfortunately, it doesn't work :/ The new totalCoins is not in the database yet.

```js
var User = require('../models/users');

User.aggregate([{
            $addFields: {
                totalCoins: {
                    $reduce: {
                        input: "$referredUsers",
                        initialValue: 0,
                        in: { $add : ["$$value", "$$this.coins"] }
                    }
                  }
                }
             },
             {$addFields:{totalCoins:{$add:["$totalCoins","$coinsEarned"]}}},
             {$out: "users"}
    ])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.sample.aggregate([
{
    $addFields: {
        totalCoins: {
            $reduce: {
                input: "$referredUsers",
                initialValue: 0,
                in: { $add : ["$$value", "$$this.coins"] }
            }
          }
        }
     },
     {$addFields:{totalCoins:{$add:["$totalCoins","$coinsEarned"]}}},
     {$out: "sample"}
])
```

Comment: Thanks, the code here is similar to the one above + it sums coinsEarned  and totalCoins. That's great :D. but im using mongoose so i did some modification to ur code ( db.sample => Users.aggreagate([...same code]) but it didnt work nothing changed in the database

Comment: Hey, doing aggregation wont update the database!! You need to do `$out` operation in order to replace the collection.  I updated my answer, please check above. Let me know if that works!

Comment: i updated the question with the new code but still it doesnt work. Do you want me to post something else ?(like the users model/schema)

Comment: Have u replaced `sample` with your actual collection name? And when you say it doesnt work, whether it means aggregation result is working and only database update is failing? Show me error details too..

Comment: Yes, as you can see i changed it to Users (which is the user model ). but i switched to native mongodb driver and used the same example and yes the new field total coins is added to each user :D. However  TotalCoins (the new field added) is Null so it didnt sum all the numbers (coinsEarned and the other ones

Comment: Its giving proper output for me. If an accumulator result is `null`, then it means the operation `$add : ["$$value", "$$this.coins"]` isnt working. Possible reason is because `$$this.coins` fetches to `null`

Comment: ok, finally it worked thank you :D, and one last question : is it possible to make the new field "totalCoins" updates automatically whenever coinsEarned or coins in reffered users are increased or do i have to call  aggregate manually  everytime i want it to update ?